# Error during request for integers relating to RGB LED on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, int, led, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am writing the code using Python 3. I've added a request in my code to ask the user to enter three numbers which specify if R, G or B is on or off (0 = off and 1 = on). For example 101 would mean that R = on, B = off and G = on.

I however keep getting an error, which I think is related to the version of python that I am using (Python 3):

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

I was following a youtube tutorial here: [Controlling a RGB LED with a raspberry pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4_R1eX9K6s)

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

R = 16
G = 20
B = 21

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(R,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(G,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(R,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(G,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(B,GPIO.HIGH)

def clearCh():
    GPIO.cleanup(R)
    GPIO.cleanup(G)
    GPIO.cleanup(B)

try:
    while True:
        request = input("RGB-->")
        if (len(request) == 3):
            GPIO.output(R, int(request[0]))
            GPIO.output(G, int(request[1]))
            GPIO.output(B, int(request[2]))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
clearCh()
```

Any tips to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Note, I have also tried the following: `if (len(str(request)) == 3):` which gave the following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

It seems `input` returned data that is an integer (data type), such as the `101` that you entered. You can try converting the data returned by `input` to a string (another data type), but you need to store it in that format to index it. Doing `len(str(request))` only converts the data in `request` to a string for that line of code, it does not affect the `request` object.

```
try:
    while True:
        request = input("RGB-->")
        request = str(request)
        if (len(request) == 3):
            GPIO.output(R, int(request[0]))
            GPIO.output(G, int(request[1]))
            GPIO.output(B, int(request[2]))
```

When you have `request` as a string data type equal to `101` then `request[0]` points to the left-most `1`, `request[1]` points to the `0`, and so on. Finally, `int()` converts those numerical strings to the integer data type.

Also, don't forget to indent the lines of code under the `if` block.

---

Lastly, a good way to test out which data type you're working with is using the `type()` command. As an experiment (or as a "sanity check"), you can add `type(request)` to your code before and after converting it to a string.

Comment: Thanks Gary. That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to answer. 
It worked after making those changes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the python built-in function `len()` does not work for integers. So what you might want to do is to make sure it is a string before measuring the length.

```
try:
    while True:
        request = str(input("RGB-->"))
        if (len(request) == 3):
        GPIO.output(R, int(request[0]))
        GPIO.output(G, int(request[1]))
        GPIO.output(B, int(request[2]))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
clearCh()
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that based on another Stack Overflow article, but then I get another error: **TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

Comment: When you retrieve the values, like `int(request[0])`, you expect `request` to be a string, but its still an integer, and integers cannot be accessed as lists. I have edited my answer to convert to string right away.